# Count the number of ways a given sequence of digits can be split with each part at most K

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Hi guys I'm practicing dynamic programming and came across the following problem:

> Given a number K, 0 <= K <= 10^100, a sequence of digits N, what is the number of possible ways of dividing N so that each part is at most K?
>
> Input:
>
> K = 8
>
> N = 123
>
> Output: 1
>
> Explanation:
>
> 123
>
> 1-23
>
> 12-3
>
> 1-2-3
>
> Are all possibilities of spliting N and only the last one is valid...

What I have achieved so far:

Let Dp[i] = the number of valid ways of dividing N, using i first digits.

Given a state, i must use the previous answer to compute new answers, we have 2 possibilities:

> Use dp[i-1] + number of valid ways that split the digit i
>
> Use dp[i-1] + number of valid ways that not split the digit i

But I'm stuck there and I don't know what to do

Thanks

Comment: Added JavaScript code to my answer, comparing a recursive (top-down) implementation of m.raynal's algorithm with the divide and conquer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dynamic programming implies that you need to think about the problem in terms of *subproblems*.

Let's denote by `N[i...]` the suffix of `N` starting at index `i` (for instance, with `N = 45678955`, we have `N[3...] = 78955`)
Let's denote by `dp[i]` the number of possible ways of dividing `N[i...]` so that each part is at most `K`.
We will also use a small function, `max_part_len(N, K, i)` which will represent the maximum length of a 'part' starting at `i`. For instance, with `N = 45678955, K = 37, i = 3`, we have `max_part_len(N, K, i) = 1` because `7 < 37` but `78 > 37`.

Now we can write the recurrence (or induction) relation on dp[i].
`dp[i] = sum_(j from 1 to max_part_len(N, K, i)) dp[i+j]`
This relation means that the the number of possible ways of dividing `N[i...]` so that each part is at most `K`, is:
The sum of the the number of possible ways of dividing `N[i+j...]` so that each part is at most `K`, for each j such that `N[i...j] <= k`.

From there the algorithm is quite straight forward if you understood the basics of dynamic programming, I leave this part to you ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think we can also use divide and conquer. Let `f(l, r)` represent the number of ways to divide the range of digits indexed from `l` to `r`, so that each part is at most `k`. Then divide the string, `45678955` in two:

```
4567    8955
```

and the result would be

```
f(4567) * f(8955)
```

plus a division with a part that includes at least one from each side of the split, so each left extension paired with all right extensions. Say `k` was 1000. Then

```
f(456) * 1 * f(955) +   // 78
f(456) * 1 * f(55) +    // 789
f(45)  * 1 * f(955)     // 678
```

where each one of the calls to `f` performs a similar divide and conquer.

Here's JavaScript code comparing a recursive (top-down) implementation of m.raynal's algorithm with this divide and conquer:

```js
function max_part_len(N, K, i){
  let d = 0;
  let a = 0;
  while (a <= K && d <= N.length - i){
    d = d + 1;
    a = Number(N.substr(i, d));
  }
  return d - 1;
}

// m.raynal's algorithm
function f(N, K, i, memo={}){
  let key = String([N, i])
  if (memo.hasOwnProperty(key))
    return memo[key];
  if (i == N.length)
    return 1
  if (i == N.length - 1)
    return (Number(N[i]) <= K) & 1

  let s = 0;

  for (let j=1; j<=max_part_len(N, K, i); j++)
    s = s + f(N, K, i + j, memo);

  return memo[key] = s;
}

// divide and conquer
function g(N, K, memo={}){
  if (memo.hasOwnProperty(N))
    return memo[N];
  if (!N)
    return memo[N] = 1;
  if (N.length == 1)
    return memo[N] = (Number(N) <= K) & 1;

  let mid = Math.floor(N.length / 2);
  let left = g(N.substr(0, mid), K);
  let right = g(N.substr(mid), K);

  let s = 0;
  let i = mid - 1;
  let j = mid;
  let str = N.substring(i, j + 1);
  while (i >= 0 && Number(str) <= K){
    if (j == N.length){
      if (i == 0){
        break;
      } else{
        i = i - 1;
        j = mid;
        str = N.substring(i, j + 1);
        continue
      }
    }
    let l = g(N.substring(0, i), K, memo);
    let r = g(N.substring(j + 1, N.length, memo), K);
    s = s + l * r;
    j = j + 1;
    str = N.substring(i, j + 1);
    if (Number(str) > K){
      j = mid;
      i = i - 1;
      str = N.substring(i, j + 1);
    }
  }

  return memo[N] = left * right + s;
}

let start = new Date;
for (let i=5; i<100000; i++){
  let k = Math.ceil(Math.random() * i)
  let ii = String(i);
  let ff = f(ii, k, 0);
}
console.log(`Running f() 100,000 times took ${ (new Date - start)/1000 } sec`)

start = new Date;
for (let i=5; i<100000; i++){
  let k = Math.ceil(Math.random() * i)
  let ii = String(i);
  let gg = g(ii, k);
}
console.log(`Running g() 100,000 times took ${ (new Date - start)/1000 } sec`)

start = new Date;
for (let i=5; i<100000; i++){
  let k = Math.ceil(Math.random() * i)
  let ii = String(i);
  let ff = f(ii, k, 0);
  let gg = g(ii, k);
  if (ff != gg){
    console.log("Mismatch found.", ii, k, ff, gg);
    break;
  }
}
console.log(`No discrepancies found between f() and g(). ${ (new Date - start)/1000 } sec`)
```